# Problems with onClickListener following getText() keyboard input in Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, android-edittext

I have a small Android Studio app to test the handling of keyboard inputs. It has an EditText field for a name, and a second EditText field for a decimal number. I am using setOnEditorActionListener to get the user input. I then store the entries in a string and double in a separate public class then attempt to display them in a TextView field when a button is clicked. I am concerned to ensure that I've actually definitely got the data in (so it can be used later by other activities).

In the public class, I initialize the string to "****" and the double to 0.0. But when I click the button to display the entered text, the four stars disappear and the field goes blank.

I haven't even tried displaying the entered number because the name text input and display are not working.

What am I doing wrong please? Any help would be much appreciated. Code follows.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            tools:context=".MainActivity">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:hint="Name"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/textin"
    android:layout_marginTop="63dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext"/>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:hint= "Number"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/numberin"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textin"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="echo"
    android:id="@+id/echo"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_below="@+id/echo"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="42dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.owner.keyboardinput;

//imports here

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final TextView echo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.echo);
    final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    final EditText textin = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textin);
    textin.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent            event)
        {
            boolean handled = false;
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT) {
                String inputText1 = textin.getText().toString();
                Common.str = inputText1;  // Store in common public class
                echo.setText(Common.str); // But input doesn't appear!
            }
            return handled;
        }
    });

    final EditText numberin = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.numberin);
    textin.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event)
        {
            boolean handled = false;
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                String inputText2 = numberin.getText().toString();
                echo.setText(inputText2);
                //Common.dbl = Double.valueOf(inputText);

                InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager)
                        getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                            inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(),
                        InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
                handled = true;
            }
            return handled;
        }
    });

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            echo.setText(Common.str);  // Field goes blank!
        }
    });
}
```

**Common.java**

```
package com.example.owner.keyboardinput;

/**
 * Created by Owner on 13/11/2015.
 */
public class Common
{
    public static String str = "****";
    public static double dbl = 0.0;
}
```

Comment: You're calling `setOnEditorActionListener()` on `textin` twice. Looks like the second call should be on `numberin`.

Comment: Mike M. That's it! Well spotted, Sir!
Put it up as an answer and I'll tick it, gladly.

Comment: MrsEd: That bit of the code was copied from the official Android developers guide. I'm still learning so am still hazy on what that does but it's needed.

Comment: MrsEd; IME stands for Input Method Editor. It's used to control what the system displays on the carriage return key of a displayed keyboard and also what the system does when that key is clicked. IME_ACTION_NEXT will cause the system to move on to the next input field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling `setOnEditorActionListener()` on the `textin` `TextView` twice. From your code, it looks like the second call should be on `numberin`.

```
...
final EditText numberin = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.numberin);
numberin.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener()
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't use `setOnEditorActionListener()` for numberin, change one of `textin.setOnEditorActionListener()` to `numberin.setOnEditorActionListener()`